# Can anyone explain how replace() works in Java?

Tags: java, function, optimization, replace

Value of str1:

```
StringBuffer str1="41415"
```

Part of my program.

```
str1=str1.replace(i,i+1,'9');
str1=str1.replace(j,j+1,'9');
```

In this if

```
i=0; j=str1.length-1;
```

This change my whole string into:

```
str1=99999;
```

I dont understand whereas:

```
str1= str1.replace(str1.charAt(i),str1.charAt(j));
```

its working fine for this.

Please explain how replace works in Java.

Comment: I don't believe the second works, because there is no method `StringBuffer.replace` which takes two parameters. I don't believe the first works, because `'9'` isn't a String. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-

Comment: String replace(char oldChar, char newChar): It replaces all the occurrences of a oldChar character with newChar character. For e.g. "pog pance".replace('p', 'd') would return dog dance.
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-replace-replacefirst-replaceall-method-examples/

Comment: Please provide a self-contained compiling code snippet. I tried to reproduce your first case and it produced `91419` for me - just as expected.

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire But str1 is a StringBuffer, not a String.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `replace` means two **completely** different things.

In `java.lang.String`, the `replace` method works like this:

### `haystack.replace("needle", "found")`

This means: Find each occurrence of the character sequence `"needle"` in the string referred to by variable `haystack`, and replace them all with the sequence `"found"`. Return a reference to the newly formed string (because java.lang.String is immutable, this `replace` does not change anything in the string you call it on; it just makes new strings.

In `java.lang.StringBuilder/Buffer`, the `replace` method means something completely different:

### `buffer.replace(5, 7, "Hello!")`

This means: Modify `buffer` (because StringBuilder/Buffer *are* mutable); delete whether was there at index 5 to 7, then put `Hello!` instead. If you had "Why Good Morning!" in there, you now have "Why GHello!d Morning!" instead.

The method then just does `return this;` - for convenience.

### Example

```
String x = "big haystack";
x.replace("haystack", "needle");
System.out.println(x);
> big haystack

// calling replace on strings only makes new ones;
// you have to assign the result:

String x = "big haystack";
String y = x.replace("haystack", "needle");
System.out.println(y);
> big needle

StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder();
z.append("big haystack");
z.replace(0, 3, "little");
System.out.println(z);
> little haystack

// Not so with StringBuilder, replace
// mutates the builder itself.
```